# How to call onNewIntent

Tags: android

I want to call onNewIntent when the first intent on onCreate was finished and the browser was closed, but I don't know can I do this. I found in android developers and goggling but I don't understand.

Can someone show me an sample example? thanks

Comment: *You* don't call `onNewIntent()`. The Android framework does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
Intent in=new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
starActivity(in);
```

For open secondactivity class from yourcurrentactivity.

and also add activity tag on manifest file.

Comment: but my onNewIntent is in the same class that onCreate just behind.

I just doing Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE), and I create new class BroadcastReceiver.

It's correct too?